# How can i only get the members that´s below the all-member?

Tags: ssas, ssms, mdx

I want to get only the members below the all-member in my crossjoin and not the all-member itself. I am trying with the "children" but i doesn´t work.. My query:

```
with
member [Measures].[Price] as 
    ([Measures].[Invoiced_Price]),
    format_string = "Currency"
select{[Measures].[Price]
} on columns,
{
    {[Product].[Product_ProdTp].Members} *
    {[Product].[Product_NoAndName].[All].children}
} on rows
```

Part of the result:

```
All 11 -  Celerifere                            $8,191,736.81
All 111 - Sauerbronn                            $2,768,882.00
All 112 - Vector                                $1,791,077.00
Bikes     Sauerbronn                            $13,941,388.88
Bikes     Vector                                "some value"
```

Here is how the hierachy looks like:

```
[Product]
 [Product_NoAndName]
  [Members]
   [All]
    Sauerbronn                          
    Vector
```

My problem is that i don´t want all the data first under the all-member and then separate, i only want it separate. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was in the the first member not the second one...

```
with
member [Measures].[Price] as 
    ([Measures].[Invoiced_Price]),
    format_string = "Currency"
select{[Measures].[Price]
} on columns,
{
    {[Product].[Product_ProdTp].[Product_ProdTp].Members} *           // here i changed
    {[Product].[Product_NoAndName].[All].children}
} on rows
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [descendants](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Descendants.html) function.

```
Descendants( [Product].[Product_NoAndName].[All], 1 )
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: it didn´t make any difference, the thing that was wrong was in the first member of the crossjoin.. but thanks, now i learned something about descendants too.